# The missing file is packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, nuget

As i have tried to restructure the path using the `..\` in the **csproj** file after building the project
it still shows the error as stated after building the project here is the error below.

[image: Error]

Also i have complete package for **Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props** as per the path which i have checked in the system where project resides, here is the path of the project below.

[image: physical path]

Now if I put `..\` or without it still won't find the path of the system here is the code after unloading the **.csproj** file below.

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />

<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />

<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

Comment: Found the solution for it as it contains the path below as well here is the code as updated <Error Condition="!Exists('packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', 'packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" /> removed '..\' on the last page of .csproj

Comment: On the top it will contain '..\' <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.8\build\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" /> but below it will be without '..\'.

Answer (score 2):

> The missing file is
>   packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props

**First**, glad to know that you have solved your issue by yourself.

**Actually**, this target node is from a file `packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` which is in your nuget package and it will add a target called `EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports` into your `xxx.csproj` file when you install `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` nuget package.

**Besides**, since you have changed the default `<Error Condition="xxxx">` node under this target due to some reasons(maybe migrate this project from somewhere into your new agent), the nuget mechanism does not recognize it and when you want to uninstall this package, the node cannot be deleted automatically, it can only be modified manually.

**In addition**, the [Error task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/error-task?view=vs-2019) in MSBuild is equivalent to interrupting the construction generation based on certain judgment conditions. **Therefore**, in your current environment, that is, if you cannot find the specified `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` file, you cannot build your project.

**Suggestion**

1) So to solve it, you can just edit the condition to the correct path of `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` as you did.

`<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.4.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" xxxx  />`

2) **Or** if your project has a lot of that, I suggest you could first delete these targets in `xxx.csproj` file and then run `update-package -reinstall` under `Tools`-->`Nuget Package Manager`-->`Package Manager Console`.

And this will reshape the nuget package according to the current environment and it can also fix DLL addresses that reference the wrong DLL and so on.